# IO : Writing and reading to the same text file from a C++ program and from another Java program simultaneously?

Tags: java, c++, io

Is it possible to read and write to the same text file with both a C++ application and a java application at the same time without writing conflicting lines / characters to it ? I have tested with two java applications for now, and it seems like it's possible to write to the file from one process even if the other process has opened the stream, but not closed it. Are there any way to lock the file so that the other process needs to wait ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, for example boost::interprocess http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/interprocess.html file locks http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.file_lock

Answer (score 0):

For two processes that are writing to the same file, as long as you flush your output buffers on line boundaries (i.e., flush after you write a newline character sequence), the data written to the file should be intervleaved nicely.

If one process is writing while another is reading from the same file, you just have to ensure that the reads don't get ahead of the writes. If a read gets an end-of-file condition (or worse, a partial data line), then you know that the reading process must wait until the writing process has finished writing another chunk of data to the file.

If you need more complicated read/write control, you should consider some kind of locking mechanism.